# SQL Parent and Child from same table but ordered by a different column

Tags: sql

I am no expert in SQL and I have a parent and child relationship in the same table. I am trying to select them as parent/child, but need to order by a different column.

Below is my table. DEPARTMENT holds the department and PARENT_DEPARTMENT indicates that, that department is a child of the parent department.

[image]

The following SQL returns the result above:

```
select m.ID, m.FIN_YEAR, m.DEPARTMENT, m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT, m.COMMENT, 
                (case m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT when '' then m.DEPARTMENT else m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT end) as PP 
                from MAS_TRE_GRANT_REG_GRANT_DEPARTMENT m 
                order by PP;
```

Now the results are correct, however I need it sorted by FIN_YEAR asc, but the department/parent department for that FIN_YEAR needs to be descending. I need the results to look like this:

[image]

If I cannot do this with SQL or there is no easy way, then I will solve it using 2 different SQL and just sort it out with the coding :)

Updated after adding ORDER BY as suggested by Simpla.

New SQL:

```
select m.ID, m.FIN_YEAR, m.DEPARTMENT, m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT, m.COMMENT, 
                (case m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT when '' then m.DEPARTMENT else m.PARENT_DEPARTMENT end) as PP 
                from MAS_TRE_GRANT_REG_GRANT_DEPARTMENT m 
                ORDER BY FIN_YEAR desc, PP asc;
```

Result not 100% as the last 2 lines should be swapped to have DEPARTMENT asc.

[image]

Comment: Simpla `ORDER BY FIN_YEAR asc, PP desc`?

Comment: Updated the question with the ORDER BY as suggested, but the last two rows are not correct. Need FIN_YEAR desc, Department asc, but still have the parent/child displaying correctly.

Comment: `ORDER BY FIN_YEAR desc, PP asc, DEPARTMENT asc`?

Comment: @jarlh, sorry, that did not work. It placed the Department 1115 below 1112.